# How can I determine the connection method used by a MySQL client?

Tags: mysql

When using a MySQL client (e.g. `mysql` or `phpmyadmin`) how can I determine whether it connected to the server using a Unix socket file or by using TCP/IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- mysql client: use the `\s` (or `status`) command. The output would have a line like one of the following:

> ```
> Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
> ```

- phpmyadmin: on the "Home" page search for `Server:`, e.g.

> Server: Localhost (Localhost via UNIX socket)

`netstat` and `sockstat` (in FreeBSD) can be used to obtain this information in shell.